# Android custom animation isn't loaded from the back stack after configuration change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I animated fragments with a custom animation that works fine at first glance.
The code is:

```
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
                    .replace(R.id.container, mOverviewFragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
```

XML Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <translate android:fromXDelta="-50%p" android:toXDelta="0"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"/>
  <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
   android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />
</set>
```

The problem exists after configuration change. When Fragment2 replaces Fragment1 and a configuration change take place, the animation don't work when I hit the back button.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

I'm very grateful about any hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this same problem.  You didn't do anything wrong; this is a known issue.

It's explained here:
[Issue 25994:   Fragment animations are not being saved across configuration changes](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25994&can=4&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)